# How to extract the inherent links from the webpage with my code (error: subscript out of bounds)?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I am rather new in webscraping but need data for my PhD project. For this, I am extracting data on different activities of MEPs from the European Parliament's website. Concretely, and where I have problems, I would like to extract the title and especially the link underlying the title of each speech from a MEP's personal page. I use a code that already worked fine several times, but here I do not succeed in getting the link, but only the title of the speech. For the links I get the error message "subscript out of bounds". I am working with RSelenium because there are several load more buttons on the individual pages I have to click first before extracting the data (which makes rvest a complicated option as far as I see it).

I am basically trying to solve this for days now, and I really do not know how to get further. I have the impression that the css selector is not actually capturing the underlying link (as it extracts the title without problems), but the class has a compounded name ("ep-a_heading ep-layout_level2") so it is not possible to go via this way either. I tried Rvest as well (ignoring the problem I would then have for the load more--button) but I still do not get to those links.

````
```{r}
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)
library(rvest, warn.conflicts=FALSE)
library(stringr)

server <- phantomjs(port=7005L)
browser <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs", port=7005L)

## this is one of the urls I will use, there are others, constructed all 
##the same way and all with the same problem
url <- 'http://www.europarl.europa.eu/meps/en/124936/MARIA_ARENA/all- 
activities/plenary-speeches/8'


browser$open() 
browser$navigate(url)

## now I identify the load more button and click on it as long as there 
##is a "load more" button on the page

more <- browser$findElement(using = "css", value=".erpl-activities- 
loadmore-button .ep_name")

while (!is.null(more)){
more$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(1)}

## I get an error message doing this in the end but it is working anyway 
##(yes, I really am a beginner!)

##Now, what I want to extract are the title of the speech and most 
##importantly: the URL.

links <- browser$findElements(using="css", ".ep-layout_level2 .ep_title") 
length(links) 


## there are 128 Speeches listed on the page

URL <- rep(NA, length(links))
Title <- rep(NA, length(links))

## after having created vectors to store the results, I apply the loop 
##function that had worked fine already many times to extract the data I 
##want

 for (i in 1:length(links)){
     URL[i] <- links[[i]]$getElementAttribute('href')[[1]]
     Title[i] <- links[[i]]$getElementText()[[1]] 
    }

speeches <- data.frame(Title, URL)
````

For this example there 128 speeches on the page, so in the end I would need a table with 128 titles and links. The code works fine when I only try for the title but for the URLs I get:

```
    `"Error in links[[i]]$getElementAttribute("href")[[1]] :   subscript out of bounds"`
```

Thank you very much for your help, I already read many posts on subscript out of bounds issues in this forum, but unfortunately I still couldn't solve the problem.

Have a great day!

Comment: Welcome to the community! Selenium is a tough nut to crack, but since rvest luckily gives you the same problem, I suspect it has more to do with the fact  that you got the selector wrong. I tried to go to the hyperlink mentioned above, but it seems to not be working? Could you check pls? Also, have you seen this? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/vignettes/selectorgadget.html I'll be online so will check back.

Comment: @AmitKohli thank you! Found my answer and I am very happy to be part of the community now! I will pay more attention to hyperlinks next time! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't seem to have a problem using rvest to get that info. No need for overhead of using selenium. You want to target the `a` tag child of that class i.e. `.ep-layout_level2 a` in order to be able to access an `href` attribute. Same selector would apply for selenium.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

page <- read_html('https://www.europarl.europa.eu/meps/en/124936/MARIA_ARENA/all-activities/plenary-speeches/8')

titles <- page %>% html_nodes('.ep-layout_level2 .ep_title') %>% html_text()  %>% gsub("\\r\\n\\t+", "", .) 
links <- page %>% html_nodes('.ep-layout_level2 a') %>% html_attr(., "href") 
results <- data.frame(titles,links)
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! It is indeed working also with Selenium (I do need Selenium though to grasp what is behind the "Load more" button, right? With your code I only get the first 20 results). But I don't understand how you got to this selector - I thought it was the wrong one and tried several combinations but I don't understand how to get there - SelectorGadget gives me ".ep-layout_level2 .ep_title" and the class in the source code is "ep-a_heading ep-layout_level2" - how did you know that the right one was ".ep-layout_level2 a"? Sorry for this probably very basic question and thanks again!

Comment: I am not a fan of selector gadget. It is usually too verbose. Read about selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) and practice [here](https://flukeout.github.io/). The gadget has given you the parent rather than the child.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a working solution based on the code you provided:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)
library(rvest, warn.conflicts=FALSE)
library(stringr)

server <- phantomjs(port=7005L)
browser <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs", port=7005L)

## this is one of the urls I will use, there are others, constructed all 
##the same way and all with the same problem
url <- 'http://www.europarl.europa.eu/meps/en/124936/MARIA_ARENA/all-activities/plenary-speeches/8'


browser$open() 
browser$navigate(url)

## now I identify the load more button and click on it as long as there 
##is a "load more" button on the page
more <- browser$findElement(using = "class",value= "erpl-activity-loadmore-button")

while ((grepl("erpl-activity-loadmore-button",more$getPageSource(),fixed=TRUE)){
  more$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(1)}

## I get an error message doing this in the end but it is working anyway 
##(yes, I really am a beginner!)

##Now, what I want to extract are the title of the speech and most 
##importantly: the URL.

links <- browser$findElements(using="class", "ep-layout_level2") 

## there are 128 Speeches listed on the page
URL <- rep(NA, length(links))
Title <- rep(NA, length(links))

## after having created vectors to store the results, I apply the loop 
##function that had worked fine already many times to extract the data I 
##want

for (i in 1:length(links)){
  l=links[[i]]$findChildElement(using="css","a")

  URL[i] <-l$getElementAttribute('href')[[1]]
  Title[i] <- links[[i]]$getElementText()[[1]] 
}

speeches <- data.frame(Title, URL)

speeches
```

The main differences are:

- In the first `findElement` I use `value= erpl-activity-loadmore-button`. Indeed the documentation says that you can not look at multiple class values at once
- Same when it comes to look for the links
- In the final loop, you need fist to select the link element in the
  `div` you selected and then read the `href` attribute

To answer your question about the error message in comments after the while loop: When you pressed enough time the "Load more" buttons it become invisible, but still exists. So when you check for `!is.null(more)`it is `TRUE` because the button still exists, but when you try to click it you get and error message because it is invisible. So you can fix it by checking it it is visible or note.

Comment: thank you! I was trying to solve this while loop-issue with your suggestion. But if I am just saying `while (more$isElementDisplayed()[[1]]){ more$clickElement() Sys.sleep(1) }` then it clicks only once and if I include a break message `while (more$isElementDisplayed()[[1]]){ more$clickElement() Sys.sleep(1); if (!more$isElementDisplayed()[[1]]) break }` then it runs until the end but I get the error message "Summary: StaleElementReference Detail: An element command failed because the referenced element is no longer attached to the DOM." Do you have a sugesstion for me?

Comment: Hi @Anne-Sophie, I found a working solution using : `(grepl("erpl-activity-loadmore-button",more$getPageSource(),fixed=TRUE)`. This check that the class associated to the button still exist in the source page. With that I obtain 128 links and no error. I updated the code in the answer. Let me know it it works for you,

Comment: Thank you so much @Chelmy88! It's indeed working like this and so I can run a whole loop extracting all this stuff automatically that's great. Only issue that I have now - I get an error message when there is exceptionnally no "load more" button but I might just add an "else" function maybe?